# Secure HMAC shared secret by encrypting authorization hash with RSA

Tags: security, encryption, hash, hmac, hmacsha1

I am considering building an API system that uses HMAC.  The server and client will have a shared secret, the client will sign the requests, the server will validate, and proceed if all is well.  The trouble with this sort of system is that the secret has to be stored in a way where it can be retrieved, such as a database.  If someone were to steal the secret, they have the key needed to do basically anything that user is authorized to do.

I was thinking that there must be a more secure alternative.  Are there any flaws with using RSA?

1. Client has the "public" key instead of a shared secret.  (The public key must still be kept secret for my use case.)
2. Client will hash the message with SHA-1 or whatever as normal.
3. Instead of adding the hash to the message directly, the hash will be encrypted via it's public key, and then sent with the message.
4. Server has the "private" key (to decrypt messages) but has no knowledge of the "public" key.  (This is the part that makes this more secure than the normal approach.  If the database is stolen, no keys are stolen that can impersonate a user.)
5. Server will decrypt the hash and validate the message as normal.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?  Are there known implementations of this or something similar?

Comment: This question is a little off-topic for Stack Overflow. Have you considered posting it at http://security.stackexchange.com or http://crypto.stackexchange.com? (Obviously check their help centres to see which is the better fit, if at all). You will need to provide more information about your security goals/threats so that others can analyse if your proposed solution meets those goals. It's likely this problem has been solved properly before, so I doubt you should be inventing your own scheme.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about security/cryptography and doesn't contain a programming question.

Comment: @Duncan Yes, my goal is not to invent my own scheme which is why when I thought of it, I should see what's wrong with it, or if there is an existing implementation.  I considered posting it on http://security.stackexchange.com, but decided Stack Overflow was just as good of a place since there are many other similar questions here.  I think it's very on-topic for both.

Comment: I guess you mean "Part of Keypair" instead of "Public Key" or maybe "Key of Public KEy Crypto System".

Comment: @eckes Yes, exactly.  I'm saying public/private keys here but for my use case, both would be kept secret but it wouldn't be a shared secret.

Comment: You dont need to keep the public key private (but you can), you just need to make sure it is not altered.

Comment: @eckes I believe I would have to keep it secret.  I'm proposing replacing the shared secret with something that is encrypted with the public key and decrypted with the private key, effectively making the secret asymmetric, relieving me from having to keep a shared secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the asymmetric cryptosystem you chose:

**(EC)Diffie-Hellman:** It does not work. Publickey is directly derived from the privatekey via the generator, e.g. [d]G = Q

**RSA:** Usually people chose fixed publickeys like 0x010001. This is done for efficiency reasons. If you take a large enough, fully random `e` and derive `d` from it there is no possibility to calculate `p` and `q` given `d` and `N` **OR** `e` and `N`. Actually they are pretty equally then and the label private and public don't make much sense anymore. All that relies on a smmyetrical property of RSA. Be sure not to walk into textbook RSA issues. And be sure to ask enough clever people about it, this is just my thoughts on it.

Comment: 0x010001 is not the public key but one of the [often used](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c) (public) exponents.

Answer (score 1):

If you base your crypto system on a proof of possession of a secret you need to, well - keep it secret :)

But yes, if you dont need the speed of a symmetric authentication then you can use a assymetric signature. Typically it is done with a signed hash, but you can also use a signed hmac.

The terminology is normally, that you sign with a secret key and validate with the public key (even when the signing operation looks like an encryption).